# Cubic Error: Unable to create customized disk file

Tags: lubuntu, error-handling

I am trying to create a customized ISO file using cubic. The first time I used cubic I made a few small tweaks to the ISO file and tested the customized ISO file, and It worked. After the confirmation that cubic worked, I edited the newly made ISO file more. But when I was finished, I got the error that cubic was unable to create the customized disk file. I was originally editing Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, So I decided to edit that ISO file instead of the one I created when I tested cubic. I deleted all the cubic files and started from scratch again, but I still got the same error. I don't seem to be getting any error codes from terminal, and I don't see anyone that has the same problem as me. Are there any fixes? I am editing using Ubuntu 23.10.

This is the Image:

[image: Error Image]